# How can find value of itemtemplate without coutrol bind

Tags: asp.net

My grid view data bind Like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="COMPANY NAME">
   <ItemTemplate>
     <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Company_Name")%>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: You want get value in  code behind?

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to see How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Answer (score 0):

You need cast control to `DataBoundLiteralControl` like:

```
 foreach (GridViewRow item in GridView1.Rows)
         var yourValue = (item.Cells[0].Controls[0] as DataBoundLiteralControl).Text;
```